# jQuery - Wrap div to a specific element

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="last"></div>
<p id="text">text</p>
<a id="link" href="xxx">link</a>
```

Suppose I have the code above, how can I wrap a `<div></div>` to the a element, and insert it after div element, the result should be:

```
<div id="last"></div>
<div><a id="link" href="xxx">link</a></div>
<p id="text">text</p>
```

Tried the code below, but not works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="last"></div>
<p id="text">text</p>
<a id="link" href="xxx">link</a>

<script>
$('#link').wrap('<div></div>').detach().insertAfter('#last');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should look like:

```
$('#link').wrap('<div></div>').parent().insertAfter('#last');
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/2/

Ref.: [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: You also need to detach it, otherwise there will be two instances afaik. Basically perform a move.

Comment: @CharlesYeung: Sorry, I missed that `.wrap()` returns the original set of elements. Updated should work now.

Comment: @Charles - There's no need to move the element at all, it's an extraneous operation :)

Answer (score 3):

`$('#link').wrap('<div></div>');` don't need to detach or insertAfter, just use wrap function

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$("#link").wrap("<div></div>").detach().insertAfter("#last")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to effectively do a Cut and Paste action on your element, you want to first wrap it in the DIV tags, detach it from the DOM and then insert it back in your target location (i.e. your "last" element):

```
$('#link').wrap('<div></div>').detach().insertAfter('#last');
```

Comment: i didn't test, but what this probably does is put a div around #link, then detach #link, then insert #link after <div id='last'> and before the empty <div> you made with wrap