# How can I insert a tag in another tag?

Tags: javascript

I have something like this generated by jquery:

`<p id="foo1">content</p>`

how i can get this using javascript?

`<pre><p id="foo1">content</p></pre>`

Comment: I think it's a good question, as long you can't find a doublicate, there is no reason to close it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Wrap div to a specific element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365053/jquery-wrap-div-to-a-specific-element)

Comment: the first part is generated by jquery, he has jquery

Answer (score 4):

In plain Javascript, you could create the new tag, insert it before your existing content, then move the content inside the new tag:

```
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
var content = document.getElementById("foo1")
content.parentNode.insertBefore(pre, content);
pre.appendChild(content);
```

---

Since you mention jQuery in the text of your question, you can also use jQuery's `.wrap()` to do the same thing.

```
$("#foo1").wrap("<pre>");
```

Comment: nice and easy, well done!

Comment: @j-doe - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML DOM appendChild() Method.
Which is used to append a node as the last child of a node.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```js
function wrap(elTarget, elWrapper) {
  elTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(elWrapper, elTarget);
  elWrapper.appendChild(elTarget);
}

wrap(document.getElementById("foo1"), document.createElement("pre"))
```

```html
<p id="foo1">content</p>
```

---

Using jQuery's [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```js
$("#foo1").wrap("<pre></pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo1">content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

User .wrap() [click](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button#submit").click(function() {
    $("p#foo1").wrap("<pre></pre>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<p id="foo1">content</p>
<button id="submit">Insert tag</button>
```